# Azure SQL Managed Instance - Create Credential not supported

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

We are attempting to create a credential on our SQL Server Azure Managed instance. The results of the script fail with message “‘CREATE CREDENTIAL’ is not supported in this version of SQL Server.”.

We are creating this credential for the purpose of restoring a database from a .bak file stored in blob storage in Azure as referenced in this [October 2018](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-get-started-restore) post.

The current version for this SQL instance is:
‘Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) – 12.0.2000.8 Nov 20 2018 21:01:54 Copyright (C) 2018 Microsoft Corporation ‘

This instance was created a couple of weeks ago with an empty database that we hoped to load from a recent backup for testing.

Can you provide advise on how we can proceed with getting the credential created?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following syntax to create credential:

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL credential_name   
WITH IDENTITY = 'identity_name'  
    [ , SECRET = 'secret' ]
```

For more details, you may refer the similar issue discussion on [GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/17959) issues.

Comment: Thank you.  This resolved the issue of creating the credential.  

We have a similar error when attempt is made to restore the database.  

RESTORE DATABASE [Web] FROM URL = 'https://somestorage.blob.core.windows.net/backups/databasebackupname.bak' WITH CREDENTIAL = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE'

Statement 'RESTORE DATABASE' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

I confirmed that the master key as well as the scoped credential were created.  I confirmed that the url is correct.

Can you recommend a solution to this error?